# NullPointerException does not occur when app is loaded independently but when imported as library I get the error

Tags: java, android, module, nullpointerexception

I download a few game apps from git to add on to my application. Individually the games run fine but when the games have been imported as libraries the games do not work.

This is the code I used to call the activity from the library class in my main app

```
 btnsnake.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intentsnake=new Intent(RewardsforadActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentsnake);
    });
```

When I call this method I get a null pointer exception on method void init() which is in another class of the library called GameView. Init method helps create the board for the game environment to run.

I am not a programmer and am doing this as a hobby any help would be appreciated. I think the major problem is that the other class(GameView) is not being instantized when main activity is called but Im unsure how to.

The error is
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cringyprithak.mcqrunch_6/com.rose.snake.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.rose.snake.GameView.init()' on a null object reference

The code for the MainActivity of the library is

```
package com.rose.snake;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int FPS = 60;
private int SPEEDStart =11 ;

private static final int STATUS_PAUSED = 1;
private static final int STATUS_START = 2;
private static final int STATUS_OVER = 3;
private static final int STATUS_PLAYING = 4;

private GameView mGameView;
private TextView mGameStatusText;
private TextView mGameScoreText;
private Button mGameBtn;

private int SPEED ;

private final AtomicInteger mGameStatus = new AtomicInteger(STATUS_START);

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGameView = findViewById(R.id.game_view);
    mGameStatusText = findViewById(R.id.game_status);
    mGameBtn = findViewById(R.id.game_control_btn);
    mGameScoreText = findViewById(R.id.game_score);
    mGameView.init();
    mGameView.setGameScoreUpdatedListener(score -> {
       mHandler.post(() -> mGameScoreText.setText("Score: " + score));
       if(score<20){SPEED=SPEEDStart- score/2;}
       else{SPEED=2;}
    });

    findViewById(R.id.up_btn).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (mGameStatus.get() == STATUS_PLAYING) {
            mGameView.setDirection(Direction.UP);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.down_btn).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (mGameStatus.get() == STATUS_PLAYING) {
            mGameView.setDirection(Direction.DOWN);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.left_btn).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (mGameStatus.get() == STATUS_PLAYING) {
            mGameView.setDirection(Direction.LEFT);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.right_btn).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (mGameStatus.get() == STATUS_PLAYING) {
            mGameView.setDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
        }
    });

    mGameBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (mGameStatus.get() == STATUS_PLAYING) {
            setGameStatus(STATUS_PAUSED);
        } else {
            setGameStatus(STATUS_PLAYING);
        }
    });

    setGameStatus(STATUS_START);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGameStatus.get() == STATUS_PLAYING) {
        setGameStatus(STATUS_PAUSED);
    }
}

private void setGameStatus(int gameStatus) {
    int prevStatus = mGameStatus.get();
    mGameStatusText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mGameBtn.setText("start");
    mGameStatus.set(gameStatus);
    switch (gameStatus) {
        case STATUS_OVER:
            mGameStatusText.setText("GAME OVER");
            break;
        case STATUS_START:
            mGameView.newGame();
            mGameStatusText.setText("START GAME");
            break;
        case STATUS_PAUSED:
            mGameStatusText.setText("GAME PAUSED");
            break;
        case STATUS_PLAYING:
            if (prevStatus == STATUS_OVER) {
                mGameView.newGame();
            }
            startGame();
            mGameStatusText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mGameBtn.setText("pause");
            break;
    }
}

private void startGame() {
    final int delay = 1000 / FPS;
    new Thread(() -> {
        int count = 0;
        while (!mGameView.isGameOver() && mGameStatus.get() != STATUS_PAUSED) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
                if (count % SPEED == 0) {
                    mGameView.next();
                    mHandler.post(mGameView::invalidate);
                }
                count++;
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
        }
        if (mGameView.isGameOver()) {
            mHandler.post(() -> setGameStatus(STATUS_OVER));
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

And the GameView is:

```
package com.rose.snake;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameView extends View {
    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GameView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public GameView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "GameView";

    private static final int MAP_SIZE = 20;
    private static final int START_X = 5;
    private static final int START_Y = 10;

    private final Point[][] mPoints = new Point[MAP_SIZE][MAP_SIZE];
    private final LinkedList<Point> mSnake = new LinkedList<>();
    private Direction mDir;

    private ScoreUpdatedListener mScoreUpdatedListener;

    private boolean mGameOver = false;

    private int mBoxSize;
    private int mBoxPadding;

    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public void init() {
        mBoxSize = getContext().getResources()
                .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.game_size) / MAP_SIZE;
        mBoxPadding = mBoxSize / 10;
    }

    public void newGame() {
        mGameOver = false;
        mDir = Direction.RIGHT;
        initMap();
        updateScore();
    }

    public void setGameScoreUpdatedListener(ScoreUpdatedListener scoreUpdatedListener) {
        mScoreUpdatedListener = scoreUpdatedListener;
    }

    private void initMap() {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < MAP_SIZE; j++) {
                mPoints[i][j] = new Point(j, i);
            }
        }
        mSnake.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Point point = getPoint(START_X + i, START_Y);
            point.type = PointType.SNAKE;
            mSnake.addFirst(point);
        }
        randomApple();
    }

    private void randomApple() {
        Random random = new Random();
        while (true) {
            Point point = getPoint(random.nextInt(MAP_SIZE),
                    random.nextInt(MAP_SIZE));
            if (point.type == PointType.EMPTY) {
                point.type = PointType.APPLE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private Point getPoint(int x, int y) {
        return mPoints[y][x];
    }

    public void next() {
        Point first = mSnake.getFirst();
        Log.d(TAG, "first: " + first.x + " " + first.y);
        Point next = getNext(first);
        Log.d(TAG, "next: " + next.x + " " + next.y);

        switch (next.type) {
            case EMPTY:
                Log.d(TAG, "next: empty");
                next.type = PointType.SNAKE;
                mSnake.addFirst(next);
                mSnake.getLast().type = PointType.EMPTY;
                mSnake.removeLast();
                break;
            case APPLE:
                Log.d(TAG, "next: apple");
                next.type = PointType.SNAKE;
                mSnake.addFirst(next);
                randomApple();
                updateScore();
                break;
            case SNAKE:
                Log.d(TAG, "next: snake");
                mGameOver = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void updateScore() {
        if (mScoreUpdatedListener != null) {
            int score = mSnake.size() - 3;
            mScoreUpdatedListener.onScoreUpdated(score);
        }
    }

    public void setDirection(Direction dir) {
        if ((dir == Direction.LEFT || dir == Direction.RIGHT) &&
                (mDir == Direction.LEFT || mDir == Direction.RIGHT)) {
            return;
        }
        if ((dir == Direction.UP || dir == Direction.DOWN) &&
                (mDir == Direction.UP || mDir == Direction.DOWN)) {
            return;
        }
        mDir = dir;
    }

    private Point getNext(Point point) {
        int x = point.x;
        int y = point.y;

        switch (mDir) {
            case UP:
                y = y == 0 ? MAP_SIZE - 1 : y - 1;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                y = y == MAP_SIZE - 1 ? 0 : y + 1;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                x = x == 0 ? MAP_SIZE - 1 : x - 1;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                x = x == MAP_SIZE - 1 ? 0 : x + 1;
                break;
        }
        return getPoint(x, y);
    }

    public boolean isGameOver() {
        return mGameOver;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (int y = 0; y < MAP_SIZE; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < MAP_SIZE; x++) {
                int left = mBoxSize * x;
                int right = left + mBoxSize;
                int top = mBoxSize * y;
                int bottom = top + mBoxSize;
                switch (getPoint(x, y).type) {
                    case APPLE:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                        break;
                    case SNAKE:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mPaint);
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        left += mBoxPadding;
                        right -= mBoxPadding;
                        top += mBoxPadding;
                        bottom -= mBoxPadding;
                        break;
                    case EMPTY:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        break;
                }
                canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mPaint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had faced the same issue as well, and it took me a long time to figure out what was wrong.

The problem was that the layout in my module had the same name as the main application for another layout, and I fixed it by changing the name of the module layout and then it worked like a charm!

In short, don't have the same layout names in both your main app and app modules.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).